# Write a slow http server to test 504 errors on client

Tags: python, client-server

Testing a client app to see how it responds to timeouts, i.e. 504 error.
I need a server which is designed to respond slowly, or not at all - in order to provoke the 504 error.
I've used:
wget httpbin.org/delay/10
And that works fine.

But, I was wondering what server side tool that is? And, is it possible to make a simple local tool that sits on a port (such as 8000) that does the same thing.

I was wondering if there is anything in "python3 -m http.server" that can be tweaked to provide this slow response.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can write your custom server and implement delays as you wish:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import time


class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        time.sleep(10)
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes("response", "utf-8"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    hostName = "localhost"
    serverPort = 8080
    webServer = HTTPServer((hostName, serverPort), MyServer)
    print("Server started http://%s:%s" % (hostName, serverPort))

    try:
        webServer.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    webServer.server_close()
    print("Server stopped.")
```

Answer (score 0):

jus start a http server in python and make handler response to get request with 504 code.

```
import http.server
import socketserver
from time import sleep


class Handler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        sleep(10)
        self.send_response(504)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(b"Delayed response")


with socketserver.TCPServer(("", 8000), Handler) as httpd:
    print(f"server running on localhost {8000}")
    httpd.serve_forever()
```